# Eloquent relationship:: Attempt to read property "product_price" on null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to access a foreign key linked to my product table but I keep getting `Attempt to read property "product_price" on null`

here's my Order model

```
public function products()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'id');
}
```

Product model

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Order::class, 'product_id');
}
```

NewOrder Mailable

```
class NewOrder extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $order;


    public function __construct(Order $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }


    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.neworder', [
            'customerName' => $this->order->customer_name,
            'orderPrice' => $this->order->products->product_price,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I want to be able to display the data in product table

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you query this relationship elocuent statement you receive an elocuent collection ($this->order->products). So you need to loop into this collection to get the model's properties.

```
foreach($this->order->products as $product)
  dd($product->product_price)

//or

$product = $this->order->products->where('id',$id)->first();
dd($product->product_price);
```